# Proof by contradiction: $c=\max (A) \wedge d=\max (B) \to \max (A \cup B ) \in \{c,d\}$

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

Let be $A,B \subseteq \Bbb{R}$, with $A \neq \emptyset $ and $B \neq \emptyset$ and $\Bbb{R}$ totally ordered by $\leq$, and $c,d \in \Bbb{R}$, with $c=\max (A)$ and $ d=\max (B)$. I must proof by contradiction the following:

"$\max (A \cup B ) \in \{c,d\}$"

Proof by contradiction: if $\max (A \cup B ) \notin \{c,d\}$ then $\max(A\cup B) \neq c \wedge \max(A \cup B) \neq d$, therefore $ \forall x \in (A \cup B) ( x \nleq \max(A) \wedge x \nleq \max(B))$, but if $x \in A \cup B$ then $x \in A \vee x \in B$, and if $x \in A$ then, by hypothesis $x \leq \max(A)$ and I have an absurd with $x \nleq \max(A)$, if $x \in B$ then $x \leq \max(B)$ and I have an absurd with $x \nleq \max(B)$

Is correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, an existentially quantified implication does not represent anything we would say in math, logic, or speech. (It is too easy to make true). Are you sure this is what you want to prove?

Comment: @Bryan, thanks for comment.. I edited my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose it weren't. Then there is an $x\in A\cup B$ such that $x>c$ and $x>d$, but $x$ is either in $A$ or $B$. Can you see why this is a problem?

Comment: if $x>c$ then $c \leq x \wedge c \neq x$ but by hypothesis $x \leq c$, then $x =c$ (an absurd with $c \neq x$); if $x>d$ then $d \leq x \wedge d \neq x$ but by hypothesis $x \leq d$, then $x =d$ (an absurd with $d \neq x$)... is correct?

Comment: Not quite. If $x\in A$ then $x\leq c$ since $c=\max(A)$. But we assumed $x>c$. Thus we cannot have $x\in A$. We can thus assume $x\in B$. But this leads to another contradiction. Our original assumption must be wrong.